# How to upload image using a form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know there are many tutorials out there but I am not able to understand them as they are just posting their codes with poor explanation plus HttpPostedFileBase is breaking my project as soon i add this to my model class project stops working with following erorr:

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: entitySet

. I want to add a foreign key to my Movies model for images and create a new model images and add pictures through it.

Movie Model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime DateReleased { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image ImageModel { get; set; }
}
```

Image Model:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UrlOfImage { get; set; }
}
```

Movie Save Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (movie.Id == 0)
        {
            movie.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
        }
        else
        {
            var movieInDb = _context.Movies.Single(m => m.Id == movie.Id);
            movieInDb.Name = movie.Name;
            movieInDb.GenreId = movie.GenreId;
            movieInDb.Stock = movie.Stock;
            movieInDb.DateReleased = movie.DateReleased;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movies");
    }

    var viewModel = new NewMovieViewModel(movie)
    {
        Genres = _context.Genres.ToList()
    };
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View("MovieForm", viewModel);
}
```

NewMovieViewModel

```
public class NewMovieViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Genre")]
    [Required]
    public int? GenreId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime? DateReleased { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    [Required]
    public int? Stock { get; set; }

    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return Id != 0 ? "Edit Movie" : "New Movie";
        }
    }

    public NewMovieViewModel()
    {
        Id = 0;
    }

    public NewMovieViewModel(Movie movie)
    {
        Id = movie.Id;
        Name = movie.Name;
        DateReleased = movie.DateReleased;
        Stock = movie.Stock;
        GenreId = movie.GenreId;
        ImageId = movie.ImageId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: @officer I wasnt able to do anything they all are using HttpPostedFileBase in their model class but for me it doesnt work as sonn as i add this to my class my project stops working and gives error Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out.

Your view should look like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadFile","Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { 
 enctype="multipart/form-data"}))  
{ 
<div>  
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new {  type= "file"}) <br />  

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />  

    @ViewBag.Message  

</div>      
}
```

Your controller should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]  
publicActionResultUploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
        {  
            string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
            string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);  
            file.SaveAs(_path);  
        }  
        ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";  
        return View();  
    }  
    catch  
    {  
        ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";  
        return View();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you think catching exceptions and throwing away the valuable exception info is really a good practice to teach?

Comment: off course it is not. I just tried to give the solution that just upload the file.exceptions can logged in a text file or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to save your blob data separately in some blob storage and the call should be an async. It will be completely separate call and maybe for a particular blob container.

Whether your page is Admin or User facing it doesn't matter. to provide good user experience you either would want to upload the image as soon as a user selects an image in a container and get back the URL, which you would be saving in the metadata table.

Or you could allow first saving all data and after that directing user to update/add an image in the record.

You also need to think through how you would be saving data (normal data and blob data) in bulk. and what would be the better approach to do these same operations in case of mobile devices? by the way, nowadays we should always think from mobile client perspective first.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my post. I tried using HttpPostedFileBase but it gives me this error Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet

Answer (score 0):

You should define parameter HttpPostedFileBase in your method

```
public Action Save(Movie movie, HttpPostedFileBase image)
```

And in your view you should have an input with name "image"

```
<input type="file" name="image"  />
```